# How to create decoder element using gst-omx plugin in android?

Tags: android-ndk, gstreamer-1.0

I am experimenting on how to use **gst-omx plugin** to access h/w decoder/encoder in Android. So I built one simple NDK C application , creating a playback pipeline using h264 omx decoder element. 
But when I try to execute I get the following instruction failed.

> **decoder = gst_element_factory_make("omxh264dec", "h264");**
>
> if (!decoder) {
>        g_printerr("**decoder elements not created.... Exiting**\n");
>        return -1; }

Please note that, prior to this,

1. I built gst-omx plugin for Android and then put this plugin into gstreamer 1.0 folder.There after using NDK to build gstreamer_android.so and my sample app.
2. Then I built a test app using NDK and gstreamer 1.0 to use omx plugin along with other plugin.

In my Android.mk, I mentioned

> GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := coreelements videoconvert audioconvert
>   audioresample playback **omx**

which builds fine without any complain. So I believe there is no problem with OMX plugin creation and packaging that into android_gstreamer.so

What am I doing wrong? is there any step that I am missing?

How to ensure, if the said element is loaded or not?

I checked gstomx.c :plugin_init, and I found the following line

> **ret |= gst_element_register (plugin, elements[i], rank, subtype);**

But couldn't figure it out what would be actual h264decoder component name and why is it failing.

Any suggestion would be a great help to me.

Thanks in advance!